# php script to login to a server through SSH

Tags: php, ssh, server, remote-access

I have a server which I can normally access only through ssh on terminal using the command `ssh 124.134.4.173 -l root` 
How can i use php to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec("ssh 124.134.4.173 -l root"); or shell_exec("ssh 124.134.4.173 -l root"); will work.